# POST returning empty array inside MVC Php app

Tags: php, post, model-view-controller

I am having difficulty understanding why my application is sending an empty POST array upon form submission in my PHP MVC app.

I have the following code in my Register/Index view:

```
<form class="form-register" action="/register/checkregister" method="post">
    <img src="/img/logo.png" class="logo">  
    <label for="name" class="sr-only">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required autofocus>
    <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required>
    <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    <label for="retypePassword" class="sr-only">Re-Type Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="retypePassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Re-type Password" required>
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="submit">Register</button><br>
     <a href="/login/index">Back to Login Page</a>
  </form>
```

I was expecting this to give me access to the $_Post array from within my register/checkRegister method.  However when I check the $_Post variable it shows that it has been submitted but with no values.

I am new to development in this way, if anyone could help with what I am doing wrong that would be great.

I tried to check within my checkRegister method in the Register controller by using this code:

```
       if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($_POST);
        echo "</pre>";

        $user_name = Request::post('name');          
        echo 'user_name = '.$user_name . '<br><br>';

        echo "POST";  

    }
```

But it returns an empty array for Post.

My code is on GitHub:

https://github.com/imoprojects/upbook

Thank you for any assistance,

Ian

Comment: Your inputs require a `name` property.

Comment: Check browser -> inspector -> network if the form was posted to controller.

Comment: @AbraCadaver thank you, that has solved it.  Much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have not added the name attribute to your input tags 
add name attribute to every input tag like this

```
<form class="form-register" action="/register/checkregister" method="post">
    <img src="/img/logo.png" class="logo">  
    <label for="name" class="sr-only">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required autofocus>
    <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" name="inputEmail" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required>
    <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="inputPassword" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    <label for="retypePassword" class="sr-only">Re-Type Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="retypePassword" id="retypePassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Re-type Password" required>
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="submit">Register</button><br>
     <a href="/login/index">Back to Login Page</a>
  </form>
```